# Почему программа не позволяет продолжить ввод после scanf("%d",choice), но если убрать ввод и подставить в choice = 1, то всё заработает?

Tags: c++, строки, scanf

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int choice = 0;

    printf("Введите номер действия:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);


    bool done = true;
    while (done == true)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Ввод текста:");
            string my_text(" ");
            getline(cin, my_text);

            cout << my_text;
            done = false;
            break;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: используйте scanf_s вместо scanf .   Но еще вопрос: что по вашему выполняет ваш код, если убрать еще ошибочный ввод кирилицы через  printf? Зачем нужна  switch вообше?

Comment: Я делаю программку, которая изменяет файл, там есть ещё пункты, но я их убрал чтобы не загромождать код